# Powershell waiting for more parameters when asking for all users from a specific OU?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, domain-controller, user-management

I want to get all the users from OU "myusers" so I have this cmdlet right here:

```
get-aduser -filter * -searchbase"ou=myusers,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

But when Im running it, powershell prints a `>>` sign.. Im new to ps, but I think it means its waiting for more input..

Why does it happen? what parameters could I add to the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mistyped the command, and waiting for a closing "

Try this:

get-aduser -filter * -searchbase "ou=myusers,dc=domain,dc=com"

Comment: no. I just wrote it wrong here on sf.. I'll fix it now

Comment: you were half right. there has to be a space between the "searchbase" and the string..